# Can I import parameters set in azure-pipeline.yml into playbook.yml

Tags: ansible, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two yaml files. One is azure-pipeline.yml

```
name: test-resources

trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipeline
      type: git
      name: test-templates

parameters:
- name: whetherYesOrNo
  type: string
  default: Yes
  values:
    - Yes
    - No

extends:
  template: pipelines/ansible-playbook-deploy.yml@pipeline
  parameters:
    folderName: test-3scale
```

As for this file, when I run the pipeline, I could choose Yes or No as options before running it.

The other one is the playbook.yml for Ansible

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true

  vars_files:
    - test_service.yml
    - "vars/test.yml"

  collections:
    - test_collection

  tasks:

    - name: Find out playbooks pwd
      shell: pwd
      register: playbook_path_output
      no_log: false
    - debug: var=playbook_path_output.stdout

    - name: echo something
      shell: echo 'test this out'
      register: playbook_ls_content_output
      no_log: false
    - debug: var=playbook_ls_content_output.stdout
```

I wish to add a condition in the playbook.yml task, so that

When I choose "Yes" when running the pipeline, task named "echo something" will run, but if I choose "No", this task will be skipped. I am really new in yaml syntax and logic. Could someone help? Many thanks!

Comment: Can I import parameters (not variables) from azure-pipeline.yml into playbook.yml?

Answer (score 0):

These runs successfully on my side(I can judge the condition with no problem, at compile time it will be expanded.):

***azure-pipeline.yml***

```
trigger: none


parameters:
- name: whetherYesOrNo
  type: string
  default: Yes
  values:
    - Yes
    - No

extends:
  template: pipelines/ansible-playbook-deploy.yml
  parameters:
    whetherYesOrNo: ${{parameters.whetherYesOrNo}}
```

***ansible-playbook-deploy.yml***

```
parameters:
- name: whetherYesOrNo
  type: string
  default: No
steps:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.whetherYesOrNo, 'Yes') }}:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Write your PowerShell commands here.
        
        Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Repository structure on my side:

[image]

If Yes:

[image]

If No:

[image]